# How to automate "Sync to head" in P4Win or P4V?

Tags: automation, perforce, synchronization

I am looking for an easy and simple solution in **P4Win** or **P4V** to schedule "*Get latest revision*" or "*Sync to head*". I would like to specify the time of when this sync is to start *i.e. 06:00 every day*.

Comment: Does it really have to be P4WIN / P4V? I'd say automation is best done in the command line, and there you have p4.

Comment: `p4 sync //Depot/dir/...#head`

Answer (score 7):

P4Win is not long for this world, so you might as well pretend it doesn't exist.  As far as I know, there is no automated task functionality in P4V.  The simplest solution is to write a batch file that syncs the desired files, using the Perforce command line client, and use a task scheduler to run it at the desired time.

```
p4 sync //depot/foo/...
```